# How to ignore 404 errors when removing an ElasticSearch alias?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to remove the alias `my_alias` on ElasticSearch 2.3 as:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_aliases' -d '
{
    "actions" : [
        { "remove" : { "index" : "*", "alias" : "my_alias" } }
    ]
}'
```

However, this alias can not exist. In such case, I get the error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "reason": "aliases [my_alias] missing",
        "resource.id": "my_alias",
        "resource.type": "aliases",
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "reason": "aliases [my_alias] missing",
                "resource.id": "my_alias",
                "resource.type": "aliases",
                "type": "aliases_not_found_exception"
            }
        ],
        "type": "aliases_not_found_exception"
    },
    "status": 404
}
```

I tried adding `ignore_unavailable` to the action as `{ "remove" : { "index" : "*", "alias" : "my_alias", "ignore_unavailable": true } }`, or simply `ignore: 404`, but to no avail. I looked at ElasticSearch's test suite for `update_aliases` in https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/7560101ec73331acb39a042bde6130e59e4bb630/rest-api-spec/src/main/resources/rest-api-spec/test/indices.update_aliases, but couldn't find a test that did this.

I'm starting to think that there's no way to do that. Am I wrong?

Comment: Can you share list of aliases by doing curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_aliases'

Comment: @vinod_vh There're no aliases at all. The point of the question is how to ignore that we're trying to remove an alias that doesn't exist.

Comment: If aliases is not there, then why are you trying to delete alias for the index..?

Comment: @vinod_vh it can be there, or it can not be there. If it's there everything works fine. If it's not, the code breaks. I would like for a way to the code to work regardless if it's there or not. Similar to what we can do in SQL with `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. There is no delete "if exists" and that is somewhat expected from any HTTP API.

However, you can definitely ignore the response for this particular case in your code instead of treating it as an error.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html explicitly documents a `must_exist` parameter.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy right! but isn't this exactly the opposite of what OP wants? Setting `must_exist` to true would not result in a non-error response when the alias does not exist.

Comment: I thought the point would be to change `must_exist` to _false_, but you're right, false is already default behavior.